# Powershell to keep regex value in a variable then build string

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to capture the value from different regexs in order to build a file list of my endpoint health checks.

I have some PS Script that parses and pull information from some txt file correctly, but I want to use the values captured in the different regexs within my script to compose new strings.

My script below read from txt file #1 and output txt file #2, all correctly.

## PS Script

```
(Get-Content 'c:\fake_path\test_stack.txt') `
      | Select-String '(^\S{5}SERVER:)(\S*)(\S{5})','(^\S*n:\"\*:)(\d*)(:"\s$)','(^\"\/)(\S*)("\s$)' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[2].Value} |
       Out-File c:\fake_path\demo_stack.txt
```

## 1 InFile

```
*****SERVER:WIN001*****
SITE.NAME:"PRJ_ABC"
bindingInformation:"*:80:" 
"/App001" 
*****SERVER:WIN002*****
SITE.NAME:"PRJ_DEF"
bindingInformation:"*:81:" 
"/App001" 
SITE.NAME:"PRJ_HIJ"
bindingInformation:"*:82:" 
"/App001" `
```

## 2 OutFile

```
WIN001
80
App001
WIN002
81
App001
82
App001`
```

However I'm hoping to use the values that are captured in my 3 different regexs below into 3 different variables, let's say $a, $b and $c.

`(Select-String '(^\S{5}SERVER:)(\S*)(\S{5})','(^\S*n:\"\*:)(\d*)(:"\s$)','(^\"\/)(\S*)("\s$)')`

My try:

`Foreach-Object 'http://' + 'a.{$_.Groups[2].Value}' + ':' + '$b.{$_.Groups[2].Value}' + '/' + '$c.{$_.Groups[2].Value}' + '/api/status'`

## Desired output of my try (written above)

A new file composed like this:

`http://WIN001:80/App001/api/status
http://WIN002:81/App001/api/status
http://WIN002:81/App001/api/status`

So as you can see I wanted to capture the regex in variables $a $b and $c, then concatenate strings like http:// + $a + ':' + $b + ..... and so for, in order to format it and produce a url.

I believe this is feasible, just lacking the background.

Welcome all the advices, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm following a more simple approach,

- each input line is checked against 3 quite simple Regular Expressions with named capture groups,
- if the 1st two match, a variable is set,
- if the last matches the url with the gathered data is output:

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\12\SO_55655078.ps1

(Get-Content '.\test_stack.txt')| ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match 'SERVER:(?<server>[^*]+)'){$Server = $Matches.Server}
    if($_ -match ':(?<port>\d{2,5}):'     ){$Port   = $Matches.Port}
    if($_ -match '^\"(?<App>[^"]+)\"'     ){
       "http://{0}:{1}{2}/api/status" -f $Server,$Port,$Matches.App
    }
} # | Set-Content '.\demo_stack.txt'
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\12\SO_55655078.ps1
http://WIN001:80/App001/api/status
http://WIN002:81/App001/api/status
http://WIN002:82/App001/api/status
```

BTW your 3rd example line is wrong, it should have port 82.

Comment: I ran your script and This definetely solved my issue, Big Thanks :-), I had the chance to learn about capturing text match into group name (the same with @AdminOfThings).

Allow me to ask you few questions: The IF statements within de ForEach-Object becomes and array?, Because I can see this {0}:{1}{2}. Then I see right after an option or switch "-f", What does it mean?. PS: Yes, my 3rd example line was wrong, Very good Catch!!! :-D

Comment: @farp332 No the if commands are processed one after the other for each line of the file, as described the 1st two ensure that `$Server`,`$Port` have the actual value when the 3rd triggers the output with the [-f Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) The `{x}` in the format string denote the positions where the following expressions/variables are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit ugly, but it works:

```
$file = Get-Content "c:\somefile.txt" -Raw
ForEach ($entry in ($file -split "(?m)^\*{5}").trim()) {
    $server = (Select-String -InputObject $entry -Pattern "(?m)(?<=SERVER:)(?<Server>.*?)(?=\*+.*$)" -AllMatches).matches.value -as [array]
    $ports = (Select-String -InputObject $entry -Pattern "(?m)(?<=:`".*?:)(?<port>\d+)(?=:`".*$)" -AllMatches).matches.value -as [array]
    $apps = (Select-String -InputObject $entry -Pattern "(?m)(?<=^`")(?<app>/.*?)(?=`".*$)" -AllMatches).matches.value -as [array]
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ports.count; $i++) {
        "http://" + $server + ":" + $ports[$i] + $apps[$i] + "/api/status" | Out-File -FilePath "NewFile.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

I used the `-Split` method to divide the file by the server entries. Each of those entries is an array element that is stored in `$entry` as the loop iterates. I am splitting by the matching any line that begins with 5 * characters (`^\*{5}`). The `.trim()` method just removes blank lines in the middle of the split output.

`$server` is an array assigned the matched text from entry that represents the server name.

- `(?m)` is the multiline modifier. This is so that `^` and `$` will match the start and end of each line.
- `(?<=SERVER:)` is a positive lookbehind to start matching at the position that proceeds the string **SERVER:**.
- `(?<Server>.*?)` is the capture group named Server that holds the server name string.
- `(?=\*+.*$)` is a positive lookahead for one or more * characters followed by any characters and then the end of the line.

`$ports` is an array assigned all of the port numbers in your bindings attribute.

- `` (?<=:`".*?:) `` is the positive lookbehind for **:"**, followed by a few characters as possible, and followed by **:**
- `(?<port>\d+)` is the named capture group port that represents your port number
- `` (?=:`".*$) `` is the positive lookahead for **:"** and then any characters until the end of the line

`$apps` is the array assigned all of the application directories that exist alone on a line

- `` (?<=^`") `` is a positive lookbehind for a line beginning with **"**
- `(?<app>/.*?)` is the capture group app that represents the matched application paths without quotes. It captures the **/** and any characters until it reaches a **"**
- `` (?=`".*$) `` is a positive lookahead checking for a " followed by any characters until the end of the line

The `for` loop assumes that there are as many port numbers as there are application paths per server. The reason each variable above is an array is so that the first element `[0]` can be accessed with the same syntax as any other element when there may only be one element present. The loop outputs a string concatenation with each iteration potentially outputting a different port and application path combination. Each string is output to `NewFile.txt`.

Comment: I first followed a similar complex approach splitting the input into server sections, until I realized that maintaining variables of current matches and outputting with Apps is much more simple.

Comment: @LotPings, your approach does seem better. I had started with a bunch of splits and then reverted back to my usual regex complexity. +1 for your approach.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks a lot for the help and the master explanation of what you did. 

I ran you script and it seems that it is not iterating with the whole servers list. It takes just 2 servers, I couldn't spot the issue.

I'm very curious of What could have happened?, cheers :-)